# ArcSegment C# Formula To Get A Specific Point on Arc WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have arc in a canvas drawn from Path with the following details. I want to get Point(115,225). Please see screenshot to get more details. Please help me getting the formula to get to point (115,225).

```
startX=250
startY=250
ArcSegment Size (70,70)
ArcSegment Point (250,200)

Computation
var meanX=(startX+startX)/2-rX;//(250+250)/2-70=180 
var meanY=(startY+ArcSegment.Point.Y)/2-rY;//(250+200)/2-70=225
//center Point (180,225)
//What is the formula if I want to get Point(115,225)
```

**XAML**

```
<Canvas Name="canvas" Background="White" Opacity="99">
         <Path Stroke="Blue" MouseLeftButtonDown="Path_MouseLeftButtonDown" >
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="250,250" IsClosed="True">
                            <ArcSegment Size="70,70" IsLargeArc="True" SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="250,200"/>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
```

**C#**

```
private void Path_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var curve = sender as Path;
            var geometry = curve.Data as PathGeometry;
            var figure = geometry.Figures.FirstOrDefault();
            var arcSegment = figure.Segments.FirstOrDefault() as ArcSegment;
            var startX = figure.StartPoint.X;
            var yStart = figure.StartPoint.Y;
            var startAngle = arcSegment.Point.X;
            var sweepAngle = arcSegment.Point.Y;
            var rX = arcSegment.Size.Width; 
            var rY = arcSegment.Size.Height; 
            var endAngle = startAngle + sweepAngle;
            var meanX = (startX + startAngle) / 2 - rX;
            var meanY = (yStart + sweepAngle) / 2 - rY;
            
        }
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Output screenshot]

Comment: I'm not at all sure I follow what you're trying to achieve. But that looks like part of a circle rathe than just any old arc.  Seems to me some sort of mean angle then use a vector or bearing to translate from the centre would be the way to go.  There is also bresenham's circle if approximate integer values would work and you need to do a lot of these computations.

Comment: Why do you need to calculate the point 115,225 if you already know the value?

Answer (score -2):

After hours of research, I found out everything is here.

```
 var geometry = path.Data as PathGeometry;
 var leftX=geometry.Bounds.Location.X;
 var topY=geometry.Bounds.Location.Y;
```

[image]

Comment: This will give you a point on the rectangular bounds of the path, not the circle. In order to get a point on the circle, you would need to calculate its center point, e.g. at (Cx,Cy), and with a radius R, get a point by from an angle A by x = Cx + R * cos(A), y = Cy + R * sin(A). Note that the angle is usually given in radians, i.e. a full circle is 2*pi, and that A=0 is a point on the positive X-axis, i.e. on the right side. You may need to add a constant value to A for a different start angle.